# Set position of a select integrated into a table

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html-table

I have a table and i sticked the table head, everything is okay but look at the select that i have integrated into my table:

[Before scrolling table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzmRH.png)

[After scrolling table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBlXj.png)

Look at the select, it goes over the table head, how can i do please ?
It's the react-responsive-select https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-select

Comment: change fix header css property z-index to maximun value

Comment: @wpdevloper_j z-index to maximum value and what else?

Comment: it will resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

change fix header CSS property z-index to a maximum value. I think it will solve your problem. Let me know if there is an issue with that.I will help you as much as I can.